# After "Auth failed" dialog, now EGit no longer asking for user name and password

Tags: android, eclipse, egit

I've been using for a while a small git repository that has been set-up for me and I'm using EGit to commit and push my changes. (it's not github or anything like it, just a repository set in a common git server)

However, whenever I was using EGit it would always ask me for my username and password (and my username would already show up, as it was probably saved somewhere, probably in my URI for the push configuration). Then, today, I mistyped my password, and EGit gave me a "Auth Failed" error. That's obviously expected, but then, whenever I tried pushing again, EGit does not ask for my Username/Password again. It just goes straight to the "Auth Failed" error screen.

I tried making a few changes to my Push configuration, such as changing protocols (initially, no protocol was defined, then I tried ssh and https) and defining my username and password on that configuration screen, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried to regenerate my id_rsa keys (which I'm not really sure I was using them before, since EGit would always ask me for username/password) to no avail.

I followed lots of possible resolutions by searching similar problems here in StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

Uninstalling and reinstalling EGit plug-in did not work. Completely deleting the Eclipse folder and reinstalling it from scratch didn't work either.

So, basically, what I want is for EGit to start asking for my username and password again.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the cause for this behavior of not asking username/password, and how do I make that work again?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 (32-bit) with Java JDK 6 update 27 32-bit and EGit 1.1.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found out how to fix this.

Turns out Eclipse had recorded my mistyped password inside its Secure Storage. All I had to do was to fix it was:

- Go to the Window > Preferences menu;
- Type in "Secure Storage" in the filter box on the top left of the Preferences window;
- Select "Secure Storage" in the list on the left;
- Select the "Contents" tab;
- Expand the [Default Secure Storage] node;
- Delete the "GIT" entry from this node.