# Gitolite Eclipse 'Auth fail'

Tags: eclipse, git, gitolite

I am trying to get a Gitolite server going on a CentOS machine, but I can't seem to access it from an Eclipse on a Windows laptop.

I can clone the admin repository from a local account and from the remote computer with command line git, (`git clone git@192.168.2.96:gitolite-admin`) but when I try to do it from Eclipse I get nothing but `Auth fail` messages.

The key is in `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh` and Eclipse's `SSH2 home` directory is pointing there.

Answer (score 0):

If your "[`Window > Preferences > Network Connections > SSH2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965118/6309)" are correct, make sure this isn't related to an [undefined GIT_SSH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7629979/6309) (following [bug 326526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326526#c11), as I mentioned in "[Egit Refuses to accept id_rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156234/6309)").

Of course, make sure you are using the latest version of EGit (otherwise you may still face bugs like [bug 356233: "EGit needs to clear cached passwords if ssh authentication fails"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356233)).
Note that if your private key has a passphrase, there is a [pending bug (352385)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352385) (or double check you [did entered your password correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037089/6309)).