# Eclipse / EGit can only connect after previous console connection

Tags: eclipse, egit, gitolite, ssh-keys

I am using Windows 7 / Eclipse Juno / Git Extension 2.43

I have set up a VM Server with UbuntuS Server & Gitolite and added a repo.
Afterwards i cloned the repo with Git Extensions. Everything fine so far. I was also able to conect with Egit via Eclipse. Both using the ssh key.

But now i have the problem that after a restart Eclipse does not connect to the repo.
When i try with Git Extension everything works as it should. The curious thing is that after the successful connection with Git Extensions Eclipse is also able to connect.

After the next restart same problem.

Also to mention is that Eclipse never asks for the passphrase of the ssh key but Git Extensions does.

Maybe Git Extensions somehow caches the passphrase for the key?

I could always start Git Extension after every reboot but thats not really what i want to do.

Any idea?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/9307690/6309 help?